# Userform won´t load after "software" update

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I made a VBA Project with 2 userforms in a verison of Office 365. But after an recent update (new computer with new installation of Office) the userforms cant be loaded. I have not been able to spot the diffrence between the Excel versions as all the versionnumbers match eachother.

I thought it was a problem with the datepicker control but error presistes even after that control is removed. I have also verified that Excel is of 32 bit verison on both computers

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Menu() <-Shortcut runs this
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() <-Userform2 Initializes
        Set UF = New UserForm1 <- Error
       Do stuff in UserForm2
End Sub
```

When the datepicker control was in the UserForm1 the error recived was:

```
Could not read some objects since they are´nt availible on this computer
```

Followed by

```
Complie error in hidden modul UserForm1.
Error usally shows when the code is incomapitble 
with the app version, platform or architecture.
```

These are the reference for the Project:

```
VBA
Excel 16 Obj. Lib.
OLE Automation
Office 16 Obj. Lib.
Forms 2 Obj. Lib.
Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP6)
```

My knowledges limt has been reached as I thought that this is was 64 bit issue. If I remove the datepicker control from UserForm1 it only shows the second error.

Comment: Are you running a 32 bit or a 64 bit Excel?

Comment: Im runing 32 bit on both computers

Comment: Have you registered (regsvr32) mscomctl.ocx and mscomct2.ocx?

Comment: That was way beyond my knowledge, I do not know what that means =/ so I would say no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you google for it you will find e.g. this:

> Download the MSCOMCTL.ocx in Microsoft Download.
>
> On search menu / Cortana search command prompt and run it as administrator by right clicking it.
>
> Copy the MSCOMCTL.ocx file to C:\Windows\SysWOW64.
>
> Navigate the command prompt to the location C:\Windows\SysWOW64 and type regsvr32 mscomctl.ocx.

Do regsvr32 both mscomctl.ocx and mscomct2.ocx

Comment: Sorry for the delay in feedback. Did´nt have access to proplematic PC untill now. The solution works great! Thanks